# Kotlin sealed class type missmatch

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I am writing sealed class to handle results of network calls:

```
sealed class Loadable<out T> {

    object Loading: Loadable<Nothing>()
    class Success<T>(val data: T): Loadable<T>()
    class Error(val exception: DomainException): Loadable<DomainException>()
}

class DomainException(override val message: String?) : Exception()
```

When I started to works with `Loadable`, I faced unexpected error:

```
fun <T> makeCall(liveData: MutableLiveData<Loadable<T>>, block: suspend () -> T) {
    val newContext = coroutineContext + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        liveData.postValue(Loadable.Error(throwable as DomainException))
    }

    launch(newContext) {
        liveData.postValue(Loadable.Loading)
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { block.invoke() }
        liveData.postValue(Loadable.Success(result))
    }
}
```

This code has no errors with `Loadable.Loading` and `Loadable.Success`, but for `Loadable.Error` I get

> Type mismatch. Required: Loadable! Found: Loadable.Error

This seems strange for me, as `Loadable.Error` is `Loadable`. Things get even more unclear, if I use `Nothing` for `Error`:

```
class Error(val exception: DomainException): Loadable<Nothing>()
```

When there is no type mismatch error. I think I miss something with generic types in kotlin. I read [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) about generics, but cannot get where I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you have a MutableLiveData with the type MutableLiveData as argument? `MutableLiveData<MutableLiveData<Loadable<T>>` and not only `MutableLiveData<Loadable<T>>`? Is this a copy and paste error?

Comment: just use : `class Error<T>(val exception: Throwable): Loadable<T>()`. As the error suggests generic type `T` cannot be, for instance a `String` and a `DomainException` - they are incompatible.  Look at kotlin `Result<T>` for reference.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, this is copy paste error, thank you for comment

Comment: @Mark, thanks, that also worked. The only thing that confuses me is `T` looks senseless, as `exception` has concrete type.